# How can I make my bot send a message to a Telegram channel, and what is the significance of adding -100 in front of the channel ID?

Tags: telegram

How to make a bot send a message to a telegram channel?

You must add -100 in front of the channel ID, this is what chatgpt told me, I tested it and it works.

“https://api.telegram.org/bot/sendMessage?chat_id=-100&text=”

Remember to add the robot as an administrator.

I searched Google for a long time but no one answered this question, thanks to chatgpt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`chat_id` for supergroups and channels with Bot API always starts with `-100`. Why Telegram did that is unknown. With MTProto there's no `-100` in front of the `chat_id`, however since you're using Bot API then this number is necessary, like I said.

For public channels you can also pass `@username` of the channel in form of a string as [documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage) describes.